# Multiple errors on openpyxl GUI program

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, openpyxl

I am making an excel GUI program in python using openpyxl and tkinter. Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string


root = Tk()
root.configure(background='light green')
root.geometry("500x500")
root.wm_title("BananaCell")

v1 = StringVar()
v2 = StringVar()
v3 = StringVar()
v4 = StringVar()


e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=v1)
e1.insert(10,'ddd')
e1.delete(0, END)
e1.pack()
e1.place(x=70, y=150)


e = Entry(root)
e.insert(10,"Sheet 1 Name: ")
e.delete(0, END)
e.pack()
e.place(x=300, y=150)

v1 = e.get()
print(v1)

def get_1():
    print(v1)

bf = Button(root, text="Enter", width=6, height=0, command=get_1)
bf.pack()
bf.place(x=15, y=147)

def askForFileName1():
    f1 = askopenfilename(title="Select Workbook 1")
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(f1))


def askForFileName2():
    f2 = askopenfilename(title="Select Workbook 2")
    wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(f2))

b = Button(root, text="Workbook 1", width=12, height=2, command=askForFileName1)
b.pack()
b.place(x=100, y=100)

b2 = Button(root, text="Workbook 2", width=12, height=2, 
command=askForFileName2)
b2.pack()
b2.place(x=300, y=100)


mainloop()

col1 = input('Column letter from Sheet 1 to compare from: ')
col2 = input('Column letter  from Sheet 2 to compare from: ')

for (col, col_1) in zip(ws.iter_cols(min_col = column_index_from_string(col1), max_col=column_index_from_string(col1)), 
ws1.iter_cols(min_col = column_index_from_string(col2), 
max_col=column_index_from_string(col2))):
    for (cell, cell_1) in zip(col, col_1):
       if cell.value != cell_1.value and cell.row == cell_1.row:
           print('Row ' + str(cell.row) + ' ' + str(cell.value) + ' is not equal to ' + str(cell_1.value) + ' ' + 'Row ' + str(cell_1.row))

exit_if = input('Press x to exit when you\'re ready: ')
```

I have two problems: A is that I need the variables `f1` and `f2` to be global somehow and B is when I press the `Enter` button in the program, it prints a blank space. Can anyone fix these problems? Any help is great

Comment: Just wondering: are you trying to re-create Excel in Tkinter?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "I need the variables f1 and f2 to be global *somehow*"? What is stopping you from making them global ie `global f1, f2` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace No I am making an excel comparing program using openpyxl but the graphics of the process(e.g buttons and text boxes) are in tkinter

Comment: @DeepSpace  when I use `global f1,f2` I get the error that `f1 is not defined`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for problem A: assign any value outside function i.e

```
f1,f2=0,0
```

and make them global inside function

```
def ask_for_filename():
    global f1 #or global f2 whatever you want
```

and everytime you use these variable outside function they give you your desired result dont forget to make them global inside function if you want them to modify as global:

```
global f1 or f2
```

Comment: Use of `global` in Python is almost always to be avoided because there is almost always a better solution such as instance variables.

Comment: ya i got . but he(the one who asked ) wants make use of global f1 and f2 so i suggest him that way. thanks

Comment: So what? Just because he thinks he needs globals, doesn't mean he does.